# How to access form resources in runtime in Windows Forms?

Tags: winforms, resources

I need to extract some resources from the MyForm.resx file in runtime. In particular, I need to access captions of controls, which are stored inside.

From what I know, resources are embedded into assembly during compilation. Knowing specific form I want access to (let it be `MyForm`) and specific name of the resource (like `lbSth.Text`), is there a way to access those resources in runtime?

Comment: From what I remember, it is a good manner to comment on a downvote.

Comment: If you want to read from a `.resx` file, you have [ResXResourceReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.resources.resxresourcereader), from a `.resources` bin file, you have [GetManifestResourceStream()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.getmanifestresourcestream) etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways, depending on what is actually needed.

1. One may use `System.Resources.ResourceManager` class. Construct it by passing a `Type` of form or control, which resources you want to access. It automatically resolves satellite assemblies and provides access to resources related to a form. The downside is that it doesn't allow iterating through key/value pairs, only accessing a resource of known key, so you have to know them in advance (for instance, process resx files beforehand)
2. It turns out, that resources in binary form are kept as embedded resources in the assembly. However, translations are being kept in satellite assemblies. To access those, use eg. `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetSatelliteAssembly()`, however keep in mind, that resources in there will have different names. For instance, `MyForm.resources` in satellite assembly will be named, eg. `MyForm.en.resources`.

   Afterwards, use `resolvedAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream()` to access embedded resource and then finally `System.Resources.ResourceReader` class to iterate through resources in that file.